# Accessing video RAM with mmap() knowing OpenGL context and visual ID

Tags: opengl, video, mmap

is it possible to learn the allocated memory range of an OpenGL context? Supposedly this memory range should then be accessed with mmap() from another process. Can this technique work, or are there fundamental problems with it?

**Update** We're using a GNU/Linux system with a modern X11 installation and can pick the video card manufacturer whose drivers support such a trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are innumerable reasons why it won't work.

First, the "allocated memory range of an OpenGL context" is always *changing*. OpenGL contexts allocate new memory and deallocate it as it decides to.

Second, I would not trust an OpenGL driver to survive under memory mapped conditions like this. Multiple OpenGL contexts can coexist, but only because they all know about each other and the driver can therefore compensate for them. It is highly unlikely that a context can assimilate changes made by another context.

Third, GPUs often work with graphics memory. Even if you can use `mmap` on GPU memory (which itself is unlikely), you're probably going to lose a lot of performance when you do. And GPU memory gets shuffled around a lot more than CPU memory.

You appear to be trying to do IPC-based graphics. Your best bet would be to have the graphics system be its own process that you communicate with via IPC methods, rather than trying to talk to OpenGL via IPC.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS and driver. It's possible with an [X-server](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-2). Although a combination of the X server, display driver and openGL means it could move the memory for a particular object around on the card when it draws it.

An easier way is probably to use an [openGL pixel/vertex buffer](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) and get the buffer pointer

Comment: That won't really work. Mapping a buffer is not guaranteed to give you a GPU memory address. Or a CPU memory address.

Comment: @Nicol - you can't mmap a buffer address but it is the only way of getting a valid memory address of an openGL buffer which is mapped intot he CPU address space

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to learn the allocated memory range of an OpenGL context?

I think you're asking for accessing the memory where a OpenGL context keeps its objects and the render output.

No. The OpenGL context is an abstract construct and have it's memory on an entirely different machine and/or architecture.

In addition to that there is no standard or even common memory layout for the contents of an OpenGL context. If you're interested in the rendering outcome only, you could tap the framebuffer device (`/dev/fb…`), though the performance will be inferior to just read back the framebuffer contents with glReadPixels. Similar goes for tapping the PCI memory range, which is virtually the same as tapping the framebuffer device.